# Create a new PdfDocument from other PdfDocument pieces that are created in memory with itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to create a new PdfDocument from other PdfDocuments that are created in memory.  I can do this by saving them to the disk and then just reading them, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with just a memory stream?  That way I could create the other pieces in memory and just place them into the new pdfdocument.  Any help would be appreciated.  Below is my attempt to do this with a memory stream but I seem to be missing something.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream )))
    {
        var doc = new Document(pdfDocument, new PageSize(298f, 178f));
        doc.SetMargins(0,0,0,0);
        var tableInfo = PageElementsFactory.BuildDefaultTable(null, 1);
        tableInfo.SetMargin(0);
        tableInfo.SetPadding(0);
        var cell = PageElementsFactory.BuildDefaultCell();
        var dataValue = DataValues[PdfConstValues.RETENTION_INFORMATION_CUSTOMER_NAME];
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(dataValue).SetFontSize(12f));
        tableInfo.AddCell(cell);
        var cell2 = PageElementsFactory.BuildDefaultCell();
        cell2.Add(new Paragraph(DataValues[PdfConstValues.RETENTION_INFORMATION_ORDER_INFO]).SetBold());
        tableInfo.AddCell(cell2);
        var cell3 = PageElementsFactory.BuildDefaultCell();
        cell3.Add(new Paragraph(DataValues[PdfConstValues.RETENTION_INFORMATION_PART_NUMBER])
            .SetFontSize(23f).SetBold());
        tableInfo.AddCell(cell3);

        doc.Add(tableInfo);
        doc.Close();
        var page = pdfDocument.GetFirstPage();
        var xObject = page.CopyAsFormXObject(newPdfDocument);
        return new Image(xObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I can do this by saving them to the disk and then just reading them, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with just a memory stream?"* - What exactly is keeping you from using `MemoryStream` instances instead of the file system? If you know how to do the former, the latter should be trivial.

Comment: Great question.  If I try to read in my stream after I close it I get an error saying I can't access a closed stream.  If I don't close the stream and try to access it I get a different error: PDF header not found.

Answer (score 0):

mkl gave me a few ideas from his comment, and after some more trial and error all I had to do was close the pdfdocument and then copy the stream to an array and create a new memory stream from it and BAM! it worked.

```
doc.Add(tableInfo);
doc.Close();
var streamInfo = stream.ToArray();
var memstreamClone = new MemoryStream(streamInfo);
memstreamClone.Position = 0;
var pdfStreamDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(memstreamClone));
var firstPage = pdfStreamDoc.GetFirstPage();
return new Image(firstPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc));
```